# How do you build iOS specific packages using SPM?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am using Swift Package Manager that doesn't having a xcodeproject file associated with it and I get an error when building through he terminal. When I call the `swift build` command I get an error that the MacOS build failed. The package I'm building doesn't support MacOS (It uses UIKit), but only iOS. I can't figure out a way to call the command to only specify that the build is targeted for iOS. I've Google searched around with no luck. Does anybody know the correct syntax if it exists to build an SPM package for iOS from the terminal?

The version of Swift I'm using is: "Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)"

I have specified the platform in the Package.swift file

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Package",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v10), ],
    products: [
...
```

I have created a sample project on github https://github.com/mike011/Swift-Package-Manager-Example. When I run `swift build` it fails with

`/git/Swift-Package-Manager-Example/Sources/Swift-Package-Manager-Example/iOSSpecificFile.swift:9:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'
import UIKit
       ^
/git/Swift-Package-Manager-Example/Sources/Swift-Package-Manager-Example/iOSSpecificFile.swift:9:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'
import UIKit
       ^`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I "solved" this by wrapping all my files in `#if !os(macOS)` `#endif` blocks. So the package builds on a Mac, but it doesn't have any content.

Comment: Isn't there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

SwiftPM doesn't currently have a way to disallow building for a specific platform but if you want you can take advantage of the minimum build version to cause compile time errors on platforms you don't support.

For example if you don't want to allow building on macOS you can use the platform version: `.macOS("99.0")` in your `platforms` section of your manifest and you will be given the compilation warnings and errors similar to this when building in Xcode:

```
The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 99.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.8 to 10.16.99
Invalid Darwin version number: macos99.0
Invalid version number in 'target x86_64-apple-macos99.0'
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and couldn't get the specific macOS error you've shown in your answer, am I missing something? *Adding this `.macOS("99")` seems to have no effect on the build nor the error message :(* Did you find any current thread on the spm's github speaking of that possible improvement? Do you have any other suggestion about a workaround?

Comment: What version of Swift/SwiftPM are you using? Are you building in Xcode? If so are you targeting your native macOS (not catalyst) instead of an iOS/tvOS/watchOS device? There is a good chance the error message will be different as versions upgrade but it should have the same behavior.

Comment: I was using `macOS(10.15.6)`, `Swift(5.3)`, **without xCode**! and I just realized that a package compiled through xCode has no error. But compiling myself using `swift build` on the same package results in the error the OP shown. I now understand that xCode might do something we don't while using `swift build`? But I'm kinda disoriented by this tho 

Comment: So doing a quick test it no longer works with `"99"` as the string you need to do `"99.0"` in order it to work with Xcode. If it is just `"99"` then you can't resolve the package manifest. I have updated my answer to account for this. Thanks for pointing out this issue and hopefully that will fix it for you.

Comment: I've tested with this new syntax, my platform line is `platforms: [.macOS("99.0"), .iOS(.v10)],` (I tried to revert the order too), but the error is still about UIKit, I can't reproduce  your output :( Just to be sure, here is my command line `swift build`

Comment: @bscothern your solution didn't work for me. Have you done anything else?

Comment: Let me try it all again and see if I can find another solution. Which tools version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here from a VERY different reason, but hope can help others (so don't downvote)

As per march 2024:

1. suppose You need to use an SPM for VisionPro, too
2. reading docs not support, but seems useful use:
   .visionOS(.v10),

but You get:
Reference to member 'v10' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

3. seems the only way is (taken "furtively" from apple samples...)

   platforms: [
   .macOS(.v13),
   .iOS(.v15),
   .custom("xros", versionString: "1.0")
   ],

Hope can help others.